# OnResponse when receiving response hangs UI thread

Tags: java, android, memory-management, android-asynctask, android-volley

I have a little application that sends a post request with an url as a parameter and I parse the response althought the response is a big binary file (to be more precise it is an mp3 so it's size is 10mb or more) and I'm writing this response in a AsyncTask in it's `doInBackground` method but I think Volley has a hard time parsing the response and I commented out the Asynctask, just left Volley receive the response and the UI hangs up at some point.

What can I do, to have my UI still responsive while receiving this big response, I first thought the fact of writing the file inside the `onResponse` was the problem but it's the receive of the response that is.

I read that Volley was Asynchronous already but it seems that my task is asking too much perhaps, if Volley is not what is needed to receive big response then perhaps another library could do the job.

My `onResponse` contains the call for the Asynctask `writeFile` and a Toast.

Here is what I get inside the logcat that I think is worth :

```
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.241ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.525ms
D/Volley: [12934] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://my_url 0x1c3b1d89 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=8481], [size=6538172], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]  
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 132(9KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(14MB) LOS objects, 29% free, 38MB/54MB, paused 8.492ms total 47.176ms
```

This is my method that gets called when I click on the button to get the file :

```
    public void retrieveFile(View view) {
    String requesturl = url;
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    url = editText.getText().toString();
    InputStreamVolleyRequest request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.POST, requesturl,
            new Response.Listener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
                    try {

                            //MyTaskParams parameters = new MyTaskParams(Filename, response);
                            //new writeFile().execute(parameters);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File downloaded in sdcard/" + Filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Download Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } ,new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO handle the error
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error:" + error.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    }, null) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Log.i("url", url);
            params.put("url", url);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack());
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

writeFile.java :

```
public class writeFile extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {

        String filename = params[0].filename;
        byte[] response = params[0].response;
        File file = new File("sdcard/", filename);
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(response);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

I tried running Volley (as suggested in the comments) in a AsyncTask and I still got the same hang up of the UI, the message in logcat are slightly different thought:

```
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.303ms                                                      
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24(768B) 
AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 51MB/51MB, paused 7.435ms total 15.271ms
D/Volley: [13037] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://my_url 0x1c3b1d89 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=4898], [size=6538172], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.055ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.209ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.314ms for cause HeapTrim
```

Here is a crash I got with a file that's about 17 mb :
Receiving the file throught an AsyncTask:

```
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 128MB to 128MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(352B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 112MB/128MB, paused 1.025ms total 30.294ms                                                                                                                
E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 33440128 byte allocation with 16270560 free bytes and 15MB until OOM"
```

I had a fatal exception after that.

Comment: instead of AsyncTask try running an Intent service as you say your file size is large.That should solve your problem

Comment: The actual problem does not lie in the AsyncTask but Volley parsing the response from the post request, the AsyncTask is not even called that the UI thread hangs up, that's the problem but I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: if Volley request is taking much time due to large file then try hitting volley request from background thread or Async Task or service whatever suits you

Comment: It is still the same the UI thread hangs up I've added to the original answer the logcat information that shows this.

Comment: I've even got a crash here while trying to use the application as it is receiving the file throught the AsyncTask. @sumit

Comment: if you're hitting volley from background how can UI thread hang??

Comment: I am calling the AsyncTask Onclick of a button and inside the AsyncTask, there is the doInBackground, where I make the Volley request and write the file. It seems that the problem here is not that Volley is hanging the UI thread, it seems there is something about Memory. @sumit